# wmctrl -a x-nautilus-session doesn't activate nautilus window

Tags: nautilus, window-management

nor

```
wmctrl -R x-nautilus-session
```

why? how to get it working? Other windows are well controlled that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
wmctrl -xF -R nautilus.Nautilus
```

Explanation of options:

- **x:** interprets the specified Windows as the WM_CLASS name.
- **F:** Modifies the behaviour of the window title matching algorithm. It will match only the full window title instead of a substring, when this option is used. Furthermore it makes the matching case sensitive.

To get a list of available windows and WM_CLASS values you can use: `wmctrl -lx`

Comment: Is there to get wmctrl to output the result? If success then output something? That way I can open the the application if there is no such window.